# Can i configure kafka consumer with kafka rest api?

Tags: rest, apache-kafka

Can I configure my kafka consumer with kafka rest? I can create consumer, subscribe and read topic. But i cant find, how configure my consumer instance. For example, `auto.commit.interval.ms`. Maybe it can only be set in native consumer?

I read documentation for kafka rest (https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/api.html#topics), but dont find answer.

Answer (score 0):

The commit interval is only with native Kafka Clients, yes. Any RESTful consumer will poll and commit in the same request if auto commits are enabled.

Comment: So the auto.commit.interval.ms parameter is useless here? I would also like to know where you read this. Is there somewhere a complete description of how the work of a native consumer and a rest consumer differs?

Comment: Rest proxy is open source if you want to look at the code

Comment: OneCricketeer, thank you.